# TypeError: Incorrect padding

Tags: python, criptografia, base64, aes

Pessoal estou tentando descriptografar AES, só que eu estou me deparando com o seguinte erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./teste2.py", line 190, in   main()
>     File "./teste2.py", line 186, in main decrypt(password)
>     File "./teste2.py", line 172, in decrypt dec = base64.b64decode(crypt.decrypt(password))
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 76, in b64decode raise TypeError(msg)
>   TypeError: Incorrect padding

Este é o meu código:

```
def decrypt(password):
    iv = ''.join(chr(random.randint(0, 0xFF)) for i in range(16))
    crypt = AES.new(password, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    dec = base64.b64decode(crypt.decrypt(password))
    print "[+] Result: %s" % dec
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tendo um erro dizendo qu a formatação do seu valor em base64 está incorreta - agora, acho que dificilmente sua senha descriptografada na biblioteca "AES" estaria em base64 (é nesse valor de retorno que você tenta aplicar a descodificação do base64)  -

Por que o processo normal para criar uma senha simétrica que vá "viajar" pela rede é: (1) criptografar a senha, (2) **co**dificar esse valor criptografado em base64 de forma que todos os caracteres sejam ASCII e digitos ou letras.

Perceba que você está fazendo as coisas na ordem inversa na sua função - tentando "decodificar" de base64 um valor devolvido pela biblioteca de criptografia que não era base64 para começar - tente só trocar o `base64.base64decode` por `base64.base64encode` -

Comment: Eu já consegui resolver esse problema, porém ele me retorna a senha assim: Ƣ.��˫"-}�R��Y�#����Υ�Ӵ�A

Comment: Note que ele não está usando a biblioteca "crypt" (seja ela qual for: a do Unix, do C, ou do PHP), simplesmente a variável é que se chama `crypt`. Mas sua observação a respeito do base64 está correta.

Comment: Obrigado - corrigido no texto.

Comment: @exploitsec:  a senha desse jeito que voc emostra demosntra que  a string contém caracteres não imprimíveis. Não sei se era sua ideia ter ela em "clear text" nesse ponto (por conta da chamada ao decrypt)  - se sim, há algo errado ali. Se só quiser uma versão imprimivel e que possa ser serializada como texto, use o base64.base64encode nesse valor

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, você está tentando usar um IV aleatório na hora de *decriptar*. O IV tem de ser aleatório quando for cifrar, mas para decifrar deve-se usar o mesmo IV usado na encriptação (e portanto você deve salvar o IV junto ao *ciphertext*, do contrário não poderá decifrá-lo).

Em segundo lugar, o que exatamente você está tentando decifrar? Não sei que biblioteca você está usando, mas pelo que entendi do seu código você está usando um campo `password` como chave (P.S. certifique-se que o tipo de dados passado à função - string ou binário - é o mesmo tipo esperado por ela) e logo depois está tentando decriptar... a própria `password`?! Sua função não deveria receber uma chave **e** uma cifra [e um IV] e usar a chave para decriptar a cifra?

Por fim, há [o problema apontado por jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118168/215): se sua função de criptografia trabalha com dados binários (como se espera de uma biblioteca Python) e sua cifra/IV estão em base64, então é preciso usar o `b64decode` no IV antes de passá-lo pra `AES.new` e na cifra antes de passá-la pra `decrypt`, e *talvez* pegar o resultado final (binário) e colocá-lo num formato conveniente pra ser tratado pelo código python (em que formato esse dado estava quando foi cifrado? foi outro código python que cifrou, ou foi outra linguagem/plataforma? e finalmente: a cifra/IV foram mesmo codificados em base64?).